# Access Device's Native Calendar In Phonegap Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How can i add an event to android device's calendar in phonegap?
I want to implement this functionality in Android Version >= 2.3
Plugins available are not working properly, Please provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

have you given this plugin a spin? https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

If something is not working as expected, just file an issue at the GitHub repo.